# How to make a jar files save input data

Tags: jar

I was just wondering if there is any way possible to make a jar file saved the values put into it. I made a simple gui that you just click the button and it outputs how many times I've clicked it. When I close the jar, it resets back to 0. Is it possible to make this save the value?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html) API.